# Is there a limit to the size of problems that your simulators can run on Qiskit Aqua?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, optimization, vqe, qaoa

I'm trying to solve QUBO problems using Qiskit QAOA and VQE solvers.
However, I have the experience that I can only solve small problems. I tried with both QAOA and VQE and both experience the same issue. I am wondering if there is a limit to the size of problems that your simulators can run on Qiskit Aqua.

Comment: could you elaborate your problem a (q)bit more in detail?